# OS X MySQL client?

Tags: osx, database, mysql

I'd like to have a nice GUI for MySQL on OS X. The app must:

- Support connecting to external databases
- Support tunneling over SSH
- Show a nice GUI for editing and creating table schema
- Give access to a MySQL command line

Nice to have:

- Easy filtering
- Free is always nice, open source is better

Is there a native OS X app that can do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I love [**Sequel Pro**](http://www.sequelpro.com/):

[image]

It supports just about everything I would ever need in a MySQL client - and I much prefer it to the command line.

- It supports connecting in just about every way, here's the login screen:

[image]

- A great GUI is presented for each table on the schema tab:

[image]

- Full command line access to the DB is available:

[image]

- One can even manage users (if one has the permissions to do so) with a nice GUI:

[image]

- It's free. Yay!
- There are little filter dropdowns, which are highly flexible (and even customizable!)

It's free, so [go download it](http://www.sequelpro.com/download)!

Comment: Great! This Sequel Pro is far better than the official client MySqlWorkbench!

Answer (score 4):

[The official Oracle product](http://www.mysql.fr/products/workbench/)

[image: The official Oracle product : MySQL Workbench]
[Download](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/)

MySQL Workbench is a unified visual tool for database architects, developers, and DBAs. 
MySQL Workbench provides data modeling, SQL development, and comprehensive administration tools for server configuration, user administration, backup, and much more.
MySQL Workbench is available on Windows, Linux and Mac OS X.

**Administration**
MySQL Workbench - Administration
Afficher une capture d'écran:
Windows, Linux, OS X

**Design**

MySQL Workbench enables a DBA, developer, or data architect to visually design, model, generate, and manage databases. It includes everything a data modeler needs for creating complex ER models, forward and reverse engineering, and also delivers key features for performing difficult change management and documentation tasks that normally require much time and effort.

**Develop**

MySQL Workbench delivers visual tools for creating, executing, and optimizing SQL queries. The SQL Editor provides color syntax highlighting, auto-complete, reuse of SQL snippets, and execution history of SQL. The Database Connections Panel enables developers to easily manage database connections. The Object Browser provides instant access to database schema and objects.

**Administer**

MySQL Workbench provides a visual console to easily administer MySQL environments and gain better visibility into databases. Developers and DBAs can use the visual tools for configuring servers, administering users, performing backup and recovery, inspecting audit data, and viewing database health.

Answer (score 2):

The application I have used the most for accessing MySQL remote and local databases and designing MySQL databases has been [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/).  Here is the [feature list](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/features.html).  It is available as a commercial and community version.  Version 6 was released last year; however, their older version, 5.x is still available as well which is helpful in some cases depending on your MySQL database server configuration.  The software is currently available for Windows, Ubuntu Linux, OS X, Fedora, RHEL, and Oracle Linux.  You can even download the source code if you wish to customize the software to your liking.

After doing some research, it appears that the only point of the four you list that the app *must* have is giving "access to a MySQL command line"; however, I felt mentioning this app would be useful to many that come across your post. And not to mention the community version is ***free***, and the support team behind it is great IMHO.  I've submitted quite a few bug and feature requests over the years and their team has been very responsive and helpful to me.  If you do encounter any bugs regarding this software, please report them at http://bugs.mysql.com.

Answer (score 1):

You may like my app [SQLPro for MySQL](http://www.mysqlui.com) ([App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sqlpro-for-mysql-gui-ui-database/id899174769?ls=1&mt=12)).

The app supports all the features you requested except being free/open source. If you are a student, I can happily provide a free license key. You just need to find my email :)

A few neat things this tool offers are:

1. The ‘database tree’ provides multiple levels of detail, including tables, columns, indexes and stored procedure. Each node has a context sensitive menu allowing you to perform actions directly related to the item you select. [image: Database tree with context menu]
2. Custom themes allowing you to have a dark environment (should you want). [image: Dark theme]
3. Query previews. Rather than a default ‘are you sure you would like to ’ SQLPro gives you a preview of the query which will be executed, allowing you to make a decision based on that (or even copy the query and run/modify it yourself). [image: Query preview]
4. When running multiple queries at once, you will receive multiple result sets, which can each be interacted with.
5. The data results from running a query works like a spreadsheet. You can select individual cells rather than needing to select a full row. This works great for copying data from the results. You can still select full rows by dragging on the row number bar to the left of the results.

There is a seven day trial available [via the website](http://www.mysqlui.com). If you purchase via our [webstore](http://www.mysqlui.com/store.php), use the promo code **STACK25** to save 25%.

Disclaimer: I'm the developer.

Answer (score 0):

JetBrains (creators of IntelliJ, Resharper, and WebStorm) have a SQL database tool called [DataGrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/) for use with many different platforms, including MySQL.

It's not free, but there is a 30 day trial. Rider (their .net IDE) also has [some database support](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/features/#databases-and-sql).