# Tool to Visualize SQL Database Schema for Linux/Windows

Tags: data-visualization, mysql

Please recommend a tool to visualize database schema.

It should be able to generate schema of existing DB.

support -  **mySQL**
 platform - **Linux/Windows**
 licence -     **free/open-source**

Something like the image depicts. Colors are not that important. 
[image: OpenCart Database Schema]

If anyone could tell me what software created the above diagram, that would be great.

Answer (score 11):

The screenshot you show comes from [WWW SQL Designer](https://github.com/ondras/wwwsqldesigner):

- free and open source (New BSD License)
- [online demo](http://ondras.zarovi.cz/sql/demo/)
- retrieve (import) schema from existing database.
- cross-platform (web application)

Description from the website:

> This tool allows you to draw and create database schemas (E-R
> diagrams) directly in browser, without the need for any external
> programs (flash). You only need JavaScript enabled. The Designer works
> perfectly in Mozillas (Firefox, Seamonkey), Internet Explorers (6, 7,
> 8), Safari and Operas. Konqueror works, but the experience is limited.
>
> Many database features are supported, such as keys, foreign key
> constraints, comments and indexes. You can either save your design
> (for further loading & modifications), print it or export as SQL
> script. It is possible to retrieve (import) schema from existing
> database.

Comment: I honestly have not understood how to import schema from existing database. It seems it requires an XML file and not an SQL file.

Answer (score 9):

Try MySQL Workbench - it is free: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

Screen shots of the visual design: http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/design/

Platforms: Windows, Linux, Mac OS X

[image]

Answer (score 8):

[SchemaCrawler](https://www.schemacrawler.com/diagramming.html) is a free, open source, and platform independent command-line tool that can generate database diagrams from an MySQL database. You can exclude tables and columns from the diagram using regular expressions. It is free and open-source.

Example diagram:
[image: Example diagram]

Sualeh Fatehi, SchemaCrawler

Comment: SchemaCrawler has moved to it's own website now: https://www.schemacrawler.com

Answer (score 7):

You can try [DbVisualizer](http://www.dbvis.com/). Most of its features I have described in my [answer to a related post](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/1332/186), so you can take a look.

In general it is a free Java-based tool for database management, that supports a large number of databases. It does support [database schema visualization](http://www.dbvis.com/features/tour/references-graphs/).

Here is an image taken from their website:
[image]

Comment: +1 This is the easiest one to get working, also for SQLite. Additionally, their EULA allows the free program to be used commercially (http://www.dbvis.com/eula/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DBeaver Community Edition](https://dbeaver.io/download/?start&os=linux&arch=x86_64).

It can create diagrams that look like this:

[image: dbeaver]

There is also a nice auto-layout feature that minimizes cross-overs of relationship-lines. Also these lines get  drawn such that they do not overlap with the table-rectangles.

(The picture above does not show this)